# "... ou pas" ou "... ou non" ?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, conjonctions

Dans la phrase ci-dessous:

> Un monostable peut être retriggerable ou non-retriggerable, c'est-à-dire qu'il tient compte des activations de T pendant  que Q vaut déjà 1 ou pas.

Je me demande si je ne devrais pas remplacer `ou pas` par `ou non`:

> Un monostable peut être retriggerable ou non-retriggerable, c'est-à-dire qu'il tient compte des activations de T pendant  que Q vaut déjà 1 ou non.

Qu'en pensez-vous ?

NB: les mots "retriggeable" et "non-retriggerable" sont bien évidements issus de l'anglais et propres à ce contexte spécifique.

Comment: Comme on dit en Nirmanide, [*p’têt ben qu’**oui**, p’têt ben qu’**non***](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%E2%80%99t%C3%AAt_ben_qu%E2%80%99oui,_p%E2%80%99t%C3%AAt_ben_qu%E2%80%99non)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les deux sont possibles mais *ou pas* me semble plus naturel.

Sinon, je reformulerais la phrase comme ceci car je la trouve peu compréhensible :

> Un monostable peut être retriggerable ou non-retriggerable. Dans le premier cas, il tient compte des activations de T indépendamment de l'état de Q.

Je me trompe peut-être cependant sur le sens attendu mais je me suis appuyé sur: [What is the difference between a nonretriggerable and retriggerable One Shot?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31367/what-is-the-difference-between-a-nonretriggerable-and-retriggerable-one-shot)

Comment: Merci ! Le lien que vous avez envoyé correspond tout à fait au contexte.